# Android: Inflate menu (add items to action bar) only on click of a button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-xml

I am trying to inflate a menu only onclick of a button in android. How do i achieve it without creating it automatically by calling onCreateOptionsMenu.
I want the menu to appear only after button is click.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First add this icon in you action R.menu... file and set the visibility as false.

Have a boolean instance variable in our java file.

```
private boolean isTickVisible = false;
```

Then you need to override OnPrepareOptions menu like below and set the visibility of the tick menu.

```
 @Override
    public void onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);

        MenuItem someMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.tick_menu_item);
        someMenuItem.setVisible(isTickVisible);
    }
```

Finally onClick event of your button do the following :

```
isTickVisible = true;
invalidateOptionsMenu(); //this will redraw your menu.
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by setting the visibility.Inflate the layout and make it visible only on clicking the button.Add a flag inside onClickListener
eg:Hide=true;

```
@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
 getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++)
       if(Hide){
            menu.getItem(i).setVisible(true);
            }
}
```